# Why dotnet run --environment Staging works, but dotnet publish --environment Staging not work

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my case, `dotnet run --environment Staging` works, it use appsetting.Staging.json

but `dotnet publish --envionment Staging` give following error.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --environment
```

I update the follow:
`setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`

and run `dotnet publish`, I hope my startup file can pickup appsetting.Staging.json, but still no success, it use DOTNET Default - Production

Comment: The --environment is not a dotnet command-line switch.  It is a ConfigurationBuilder/WebHostBuilder argument if you have things set up correctly to recognize it.
https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: dotnet publish has a -c configuration option. Maybe you could use that if you are trying to publish a Debug build?

Comment: There's been some buzz about eliminating dotnet publish altogether and just using Release build for deployment
https://twitter.com/DamianEdwards/status/1369442704896237570?s=09

Comment: @RexHenderson, before I post this question, I found the link you post here, and I have followed exactly in the post, one of the options is use windows cmd to change environment variable. But no success

Comment: Are you publishing to a folder?  Are you executing the application .exe from this publish folder? If so, then all you need do is 'set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging'   right before you execute the .exe
If you are using the template defaults it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue.

never trust this link [andrewlock.net](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/)

In his document, he asked me to set environment name via cmd, which is no use at all.

The proper solution is:

in your csproj file, add the following

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' Or '$(Configuration)' == 'Development'">
    <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != '' AND '$(Configuration)' == 'Staging' ">
    <EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != '' AND '$(Configuration)' == 'Production' ">
    <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then, in the publish command, use the following for different environment

```
dotnet publish --configuration Staging
dotnet publish --configuration Production
```

EnvironmentName is not set via cmd, but inside the project itself.

Comment: _"In his document, he asked me to set environment name via cmd, which is no use at all."_ - in the question you state that you have used `setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"`, have you used the same cmd window to run the app? Cause the linked post clearly says _"Note that the environment variable is not set in the current open window."_.